# Email templates

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to fully customize the HTML emails being send out to customers in any tier plans? (the support agent was unable to answer this question)

If not, are there any plans on adding more customization to the HTML email branding? I'm having issues with the recommended width and height as it looks terrible on an high density pixel ratio screen, ideally I could go around that by uploading it twice the size and then lowering the size down by defining the width of the image, is this something that would be possible in the future? Or even lets say, separate image files for web and emails?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of system or HW that you're referring to? Is it your senders or signers who have these devices?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to fully customize the HTML emails being sent out to customers in any tier plans?

Not beyond the branding feature. Higher tier plans support multiple branding files, eg for different departments within a large org.

Sending emails with HTML to people that could be using any type of mail reading software and hardware from low-res small mobile devices to the high density pixel-ratio screens that your signers have is always a matter of tough compromise.